# fastest way to compare strings in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm writing a script in Python that will allow the user to input a string, which will be a command that instructs the script to perform a specific action.  For the sake of argument, I'll say my command list is:

```
lock
read
write
request
log
```

Now, I want the user to be able to enter the word "log" and it will peform a specific action, which is very simple.  However, I would like to match partial words.  So, for example, if a user enters "lo", it should match "lock", as it's higher in the list.  I've tried using strncmp from libc using ctypes to accomplish this, but have yet to make heads or tails of it.

Comment: How much does speed actually matter?  Assuming this is run a single time when the user enters a command, and run over a small set of commands (less than 1000), even the most inefficient (practical) implementation will return in under a millisecond -- which will appear instantaneous to the user.

Comment: This is a network application running on the Twisted framework, and may have up to 50 users entering commands at the same time, so there could be a potential lag if all 50 are entering commands and I'm inefficiently parsing them.

Comment: twisted is threaded. you still won't notice any impact. most computers could compare 10,000 or more strings in the time it takes for your finger to press a key. This is called premature optimisation, you're wasting your time on trivialities.

Comment: Build simply, then measure where your performance problems are.  It seems really unlikely that it will be the command parsing.

Comment: @SpliFF I agree with the spirit of the message, however, Twisted is not threaded. At least, not unless you make it so (e.g. deferToThread).

Comment: Mike, is this some sort of terminal server (thinking of your other question about ANSI escape sequences)?  If it's a sort of massively multi-user server with realtime interactive response, you may well be justified in having a focus on performance, to the point where a few milliseconds difference will actually matter.  Users will notice a 50ms delay in such cases.  You presumably already know that... making it clear to folks here what timescale *does* matter to you might help you get to-the-point responses without all the possibly unwanted advice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are accepting input from a user, then why are you worried about the speed of comparison?  Even the slowest technique will be far faster than the user can perceive.  Use the simplest most understandable code you can, and leave efficiency concerns for tight inner loops.

```
cmds = [
    "lock",
    "read",
    "write",
    "request",
    "log",
    ]

def match_cmd(s):
    matched = [c for c in cmds if c.startswith(s)]
    if matched:
        return matched[0]
```

Comment: wish I could upvote that 10x. That's why I love UI development so much -- time scales are absolutely (well, relatively) enormous. You can take a leisurly 100ms to do something and nobody notices.

Answer (score 5):

This will do what you want:

```
def select_command(commands, user_input):
    user_input = user_input.strip().lower()
    for command in commands:
        if command.startswith(user_input):
            return command
    return None
```

**However:**

You seem overworried about the wrong thing. So 50 users means 50 milliseconds -- you're not going to be run out of town for that kind of "lag". Worry about inefficient database access or problems caused by users typing "r" and getting "read" when they thought they'd get "request". Minimising user keystrokes at the risk of errors is so 1960s that it's not funny. What are they using? ASR33 teletypes? At the very least you could insist on a unique match -- "rea" for read and "req" for request.

Answer (score 3):

**This is optimized at runtime like you requested...** (although most likely not needed)

Here is a simple bit of code which will take an input dictionary of command mapped to function, and results in an output dictionary of all non-duplicate sub commands mapped to the same function.

So you run this when you start your service, and then you have 100% optimized lookups.  I am sure there is a more clever way to do this, so feel free to edit.

```
commands = {
  'log': log_function,
  'exit': exit_function,
  'foo': foo_function,
  'line': line_function,
  }

cmap = {}
kill = set()
for command in commands:
  for pos in range(len(1,command)):
    subcommand = command[0:pos]
    if subcommand in cmap:
      kill.add(subcommand)
      del(cmap[subcommand])
    if subcommand not in kill:
      cmap[subcommand] = commands[command]

#cmap now is the following - notice the duplicate prefixes removed?
{
  'lo': log_function,
  'log': log_function,
  'e': exit_function,
  'ex': exit_function,
  'exi': exit_function,
  'exit': exit_function,
  'f' : foo_function,
  'fo' : foo_function,
  'foo' : foo_function,
  'li' : line_function,
  'lin' : line_function,
  'line' : line_function,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use startswith

eg

```
myword = "lock"
if myword.startswith("lo"):
   print "ok"
```

or if you want to find "lo" in the word, regardless of position, just use the "in" operator

```
if "lo" in myword
```

therefore, one way you can do this:

```
for cmd in ["lock","read","write","request","log"]:
    if cmd.startswith(userinput):
        print cmd
        break
```

Comment: @ghostdog74, better read in more detail: "I would like to match partial words. So, for example, if a user enters "lo", it should match "lock", as it's higher in the list."

Comment: Peter Hansen is correct.  Partial words will need to be matched to make the system easier to use.  I will (Eventually) have some complex commands, and being able to abbreviate them to a single letter is very convenient.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at using the readline python library, rather than reinventing the wheel.
The user will have to hit tab to complete the word, but you can set readline up so that tab matches as far as possible or cycles through all words starting wit the current stub.

This seems to be a fairly decent introduction to readline in python http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/readline/index.html

Answer (score 1):

`jaro_winkler()` in [python-Levenshtein](http://www.michael-noll.com/wiki/Python-Levenshtein) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with your favorite string compare function. Fairly fast, and to the point.

```
matches = ( x for x in list if x[:len(stringToSearchFor)] == stringToSearchFor )
print matches[0]
```

Comment: (1) see `http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith`
(2) don't use `list`; it will shadow the `list()` built-in.

Answer (score 0):

This is adapted from [J.Tauber's Trie implementation in Python](http://jtauber.com/blog/2005/02/10/updated_python_trie_implementation/), which you could compare and/or re-adapt with whatever extra features you need.  See also the [Wikipedia entry on tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = [None, {}]

    def add(self, key):
        curr_node = self.root
        for ch in key:
            curr_node = curr_node[1].setdefault(ch, [key, {}])
        curr_node[0] = key

    def find(self, key):
        curr_node = self.root
        for ch in key:
            try:
                curr_node = curr_node[1][ch]
            except KeyError:
                return None
        return curr_node[0]
```

Setup (order of addition matters!):

```
t = Trie()
for word in [
   'lock',
   'read',
   'write',
   'request',
   'log']:
   t.add(word)
```

Then call like this:

```
>>> t.find('lo')
'lock'
>>> t.find('log')
'log'
>>> t.find('req')
'request'
>>> t.find('requiem')
>>>
```

Comment: No kidding, but yet another "iterate over list with startswith()" seemed *really* boring. ;-)

Comment: At least my stratswith effort addressed the OP's (pointless) efficiency concern by baling out upon the first match :-)

Comment: @John, ah, so you think it's acceptable that if "lo" also appears in the list, but after "lock", that entering "lo" will return "lock" as the match?  I did not think that.

Comment: @Peter Hansen: +1 *non* *sequitur* of the month. You have no reason for thinking that I think that that is acceptable. It's clearly not acceptable. However it's a natural consequence of what the OP said he wanted. He's obviously aware that order in the list matters. One would need to trust (a) that he wouldn't put "lo" after "lock" or "log" (b) failing that, that he would test his code and find out that a user could not access the "lo" functionality.

Comment: @John, It can hardly be a "natural consequence", when my solution doesn't suffer from the problem.  I'll also note that "bailing on the first match" while the overall solution is still slower because it's traversing a long list of commands is hardly a good way to address performance concerns.  (Of course, we'd need more background on performance needs and actual list size before we'd accomplish anything by that discussion.)

Comment: @Peter: Your solution doesn't suffer from the problem either because of serendipitous accident or (more charitably) because you imposed an extra constraint on top of the OP's implicit left-to-right ordering. Baling out on the first match: you missed the smiley in my comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your Q correctly, you want a snippet that will return the answer as soon as it has it, without traversing further through your 'command list.' This should do what you want:

```
from itertools import ifilter

def check_input(some_string, code_book) :
    for q in ifilter(code_book.__contains__, some_string) :
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import timeit

cmds = []
for i in range(1,10000):
    cmds.append("test")

def get_cmds(user_input):
    return [c for c in cmds if c.startswith(user_input)]

if __name__=='__main__':
    t = timeit.Timer("get_cmds('te')", "from __main__ import get_cmds")
    print "%0.3f seconds" % (t.timeit(number=1))

#>>> 0.008 seconds
```

So basically, per my comment, you're asking how to optimise an operation that takes no measurable time or CPU. I used 10,000 commands here and the test string matches every one just to show that even under extreme circumstances you could still have hundreds of users doing this and they would never see any lag.