# Can't compare input strings in Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-3.2

I'm experiencing a very odd problem in Python. These two didn't seem to help:

[Validating user input strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635073/validating-user-input-strings-in-python) and [fastest way to compare strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053937/fastest-way-to-compare-strings-in-python)

I've written the following small program, test.py:

```
import sys
while True:
    print("\n")
    print("Type exit to exit: ")

    inputvar = str(input())
    print("Input: "+inputvar)

    if inputvar == 'exit':
        print("Exiting!")
        sys.exit("\n\nProgram quit.")
    else:
        print("Still here")
```

The current version doesn't seem to quit with `exit`, `'exit'` or `"exit"`. Using `input()` instead of `str(input())` doesn't seem to make a difference, and using `is` or `in` instead of `==` doesn't make a difference either.

I'm using Python 3.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Works for me in Python 3 exactly as posted.

Comment: `input()` already returns a string, so `str(input())` won't make any difference. `is` compares *identity*, not *equality*, so is a bad choice for string comparisons; `==` is correct. If you're saying that `'exit' != 'exit'` in your code, you have a serious problem; are you sure you haven't introduced some whitepace? Try `inputvar.strip()` or `print(repr(inputvar))` to see what's going on.

Comment: Try adding `inputvar.strip()` just in case there is trailing whitespace for some reason.

Comment: works for me also, but on debian with python 3.4...

Comment: print(repr(inputvar)) gives 'exit\r', apparently a carriage return was added. It works with .strip() added!

Answer (score 7):

There was a bug in Python 3.2.0 where the trailing `\r` was not removed from  `input()` :  [details here](https://bugs.python.org/issue11272).  I suggest you upgrade (it was fixed very rapidly in 3.2.1).  If you can't then:

```
inputvar = input().rstrip()
```

Answer (score -3):

input() return a string

so no need to use str(input())

or you can use

```
inputvar = input().strip()
```